# Trouble with closing sq lite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm having trouble with how I can close my SQLite DB properly.  
When I run my application, one of the activities uses my `DBAdapter` class to retrieve a row of info from my DB and then I want to close it right away to avoid any issues if the user hits the back button or closes the app.

But when I switch to another activity that uses the same DB and adapter I get an error.

Here is the activity level code:

```
PlayerSummonDbAdapter PlayerDbAdapter;
PlayerDbAdapter = new PlayerSummonDbAdapter(this);
PlayerDbAdapter.open();
        mySummon = new Summon();
        mySummon = PlayerDbAdapter.retrieveSummon(1, summonName);
PlayerDbAdapter.close();
```

---

And here is the `open()` and `lose()` methods in my adapter:

```
public PlayerSummonDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new PlayerSummonSQLiteHelper(context);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
}
public void close() {
        database.close();
        dbHelper.close();   
    }
```

---

And here is a sample of the error log:  It says that **close() was not called on the database** but I do close it.  At least I think I did.

```
06-21 00:10:35.928: I/dalvikvm(23203): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
06-21 00:10:35.928: I/dalvikvm(23203): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40567168 on Moves that has not been deactivated or closed
06-21 00:10:35.928: I/dalvikvm(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:620)
06-21 00:10:35.928: I/dalvikvm(23203):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203): close() was never explicitly called on database '/mnt/sdcard/Summon.sqlite' 
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at com.willmer.SummonListAdapter.open(SummonListAdapter.java:55)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at com.willmer.BattleActivity.onCreate(BattleActivity.java:78)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3688)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-21 00:10:35.932: E/Database(23203):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.willmer/databases/PlayerSummons.db' 
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:635)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at com.willmer.PlayerSummonDbAdapter.open(PlayerSummonDbAdapter.java:67)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at com.willmer.BattleActivity.CaptureSummon(BattleActivity.java:563)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at com.willmer.BattleActivity.onClick(BattleActivity.java:146)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3688)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-21 00:10:35.944: E/Database(23203):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: first try to close **mySummon**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you didn't close the cursor used.

Note: there are better APIs available in the support library for android which takes care of most of this trouble.

Comment: Is that evident from the error log?  If so what line, so that I can understand and see it again if it comes up.

Comment: This is a tricky one. Old android versions didn't had this error, and caused memory leaks .etc. So Google added a check on the finalizer of the cursor to release the native objects, and throw an error so the developer knows he forgot this. Check the first 2 lines of the log. Error doesn't say where you forgot to close. It only says that you got a cursor being finalized, but was not closed to release the underlying native objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your database in `onDestroy`.

Add this to your code

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (dbHelper != null) {
        database.close();  
        dbHelper .close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes up a lot, but basically:

- close *cursors* immediately after using (probably in a `finally` block)
- you don't need to close the database explicitly, it will be automatically closed when you process dies.

Opening the database has some overhead, so opening and closing repeatedly is not a good idea. Make your database helper a singleton, and use it throughout your application. Do not call its `close()` method from your app.

Comment: I will have to look into those suggestions.